# What does a trailing slash in the parameter of require.resolve() mean?

Tags: node.js, webpack, require

While setting up a build system with webpack 5.1.1 today webpack informed me that since 4.x the API has changed and webpack no longer includes polyfills for Node.js core modules by default, but that I can include one myself by using `require.resolve()` to add fallbacks for when these are missing (which they obviously are in non-Node contexts).

So far so good. What was not clear however was why in some of these instructions a trailing slash was put after the name of the module whereas in other cases there was no trailing slash.

Excerpts from the log:

Example without trailing slash:

```
If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
```

Example with trailing slash:

```
If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/") }'
    - install 'buffer'
```

Which brings me to my question: What does a trailing slash in the parameter of `require.resolve()` mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is the following. `buffer` is one of core node modules. If you do `require.resolve('buffer')` node module resolution algorithm will find this file `lib/buffer.js`. But you want it to actually bypass core module and lookup in `node_modules` folder. Adding trailing slash does the trick.

From buffer module [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer)

> To depend on this module explicitly (without browserify), require it
> like this:
>
> `var Buffer = require('buffer/').Buffer  // note: the trailing slash is important!`
>
> To require this module explicitly, use `require('buffer/')` which tells
> the node.js module lookup algorithm (also used by browserify) to use
> the npm module named buffer instead of the node.js core module named
> buffer!